# How to create multiple random Google forms with a fixed number of Multiple Choice Questions with a single script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

**Disclaimer: I just started with JavaScripts/GoogleForms**

I want to validate some data with a GoogleForm that I've created. Each section contains 5 multiple choice questions. In the example below I've shown how I add one question to the section.

```
    // Sentence 1
    sentence = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
    choices = [
      sentence.createChoice('Answer I'),
      sentence.createChoice('Answer II'),
      sentence.createChoice('Answer III'),
      ]
    sentence.setTitle(pred_1) // pred_1 -> Variable extracted from the dataset
    .setChoices(choices);
```

In the end, I can build an excellent-looking form that contains 20 sections with five questions each based one a single dataset in my Google Drive Folder.

However, I want to extend this. I have ten different datasets that I want to have evaluated. A straightforward approach is copying the script ten times and pointing the script towards a different dataset. However, with this approach, I have to run the script ten times, and every time I adjust something (e.g. in the Title/HelpText), I have to rerun all the scripts.

I was thinking there should be a solution where I just read all the file inside my Drive folder and run my main scripts that produces the forms for multiple dataset. I was thinking something like this:

```
function createForms() {

  // Folder with data
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDERID')
  
  // List files
  var files = folder.getFiles()

  for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
      createMultipleChoiceForm(files[i]) // Function that creates a single form
  }
}
```

This does unfortunately does not work at all (it does not give any errors, but does not produce anything).

***EDIT:***
*This does actually work, but it creates a new form every time without saving it (it overruns the previous version).*

I final approach is of course concatenating all the 10 datasets, and sample them from within the Google Script editor. But I still want to end up with ten different form (so I can send them to different people.

I hope anyone can give me some pointers in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to learn a bit about algorithms and data structures. Try [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript). See [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/13045193)

Comment: I understand this is a rather weak question, but I do not need any more information about algorithms and data structures, I just need some pointers in the right direction. I am a Python programmer, not a JavaScript programmer.

Comment: Google Apps Script is modern JavaScript and thus supports all major functional programming concepts such as OOP and closures. Parametrize your functions the same way you would do in Python. See [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/). Note that [Folder.getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfiles) returns a `FileIterator` object rather than an array. You are calling `createMultipleChoiceForm()` with an `undefined` parameter every time.

Comment: I see your point, I use a variable as a parameter in my function that point towards the correct dataset, apologies if this was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Folder.getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfiles) method returns a `FileIterator` object rather than an array. The code in the question ends up calling `createMultipleChoiceForm()` with an `undefined` parameter every time.

To make it work, replace the `for` loop with this pattern:

```js
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    createMultipleChoiceForm(files.next());
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, accepted the answer. It does create multiple forms, but the main problem still exists: it overwrites the previous form.